# Applying styles in javascript with a for-in loop

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

So I have an object full of key-value pairs that describe the intended style of an element and I am trying to apply that style to an element by looping through the object like this:

```
element = document.createElement('div');   
style = {width : '220px', height : '100%', left : '0', height : '0', position : 'relative'}
for (x in style){
    element.style.x = style[x];
}
```

And yet the element remains without a style. This seems so simple that I cannot figure out what might be going wrong,so I assume I am missing something incredibly obvious. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the property `x` on each iteration. Instead, use the value of `x` like so:

```
element.style[x] = style[x];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
element = document.createElement('div');   
style = {width : '220px', height : '100%', left : '0', height : '0', position : 'relative'}
for (x in style){
    element.style[x] = style[x];
}
```